# SQL LEFT SEMI JOIN with Table 1 and Table 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server: `Table1` and `Table2`.

I want to use use a Left Semi Join or Semi Join so that I can have less duplication from Table2. I want my query to contain columns from both tables. Currently, I'm only able to reference Table1.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT
    A.Date,
    A.Name,
    A.DOB,
    B.Gender
FROM 
    Table1 AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM Table2 AS B WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE A.main = B.main)
    AND A.date BETWEEN '9/01/2019 00:00:00.000' AND '12/12/2019 23:59:59.000'
```

I keep getting an error that "B.Gender" could not be bound. None of my `Table2` references works. How can my obtain have specific columns from Table1 and Table2 in my query?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *really* using. Why are you using `NOLOCK` everywhere (which implies SQL Server). [Bad Habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: A semi join by definition only contains columns from one table. If you need columns from both table you need a join

Comment: If you want to use `table2` columns in your output then it will need to be up in your `FROM` clause and joined properly. Right now `table2` is merely being used to filter using a correlated subquery. Please, so we can help better, share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: @demidee . . . I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is obviously SQL Server.

Comment: Please supply example data and desired results. And make clear whether or not there can be multiple `B.Gender` for a `B.main` (and if so what the expected results for that case are)

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
SELECT a.date, a.Name , a.DOB, b.Gender
FROM Table1 a CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) b.*
      FROM Table2 b
      WHERE A.main = B.main
     ) b
WHERE a.date >= '2019-09-01' and
      a.date < '2019-12-13';
```

Note that I removed the `(NOLOCK)` hint -- you probably don't fully understand the implications of reading dirty data pages.  In addition  simplified the date logic.  Hopefully I interpreted the dates correctly.

Comment: It is not clear to me from the question that the desired semantics are to pick a random matching row from Table2

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . This does not choose a *random* row, it chooses an *indeterminate* row.  In any case, what else would returning a value from a semi-join imply?

Comment: Who knows? the entire concept doesn't make sense, Maybe they want to just return the distinct matching values from the RHS.